# labeling ListPlot data and drawing vectors

Tags: plotting, labeling

I would like to plot these x,y data:

```
FkFl2={{0.108705, 0.505448}, {0.358493, 0.0753008}, {-0.418082, 0.0156307}, {-0.00893736, -0.519801}, {0.341173, -0.170573},{0.139561, 0.546447},{0.0991457, 0.236118}, {-0.408699,0.060441}, {-0.371379, 0.0200262}, {-0.411535, 0.0433609}, {0.254496, -0.28112}}
```

adding labels, taken from the matrix below, and coordinates vectors for the corresponding point. The plot axes are labelled "F"k and "F"l (k and l defined in the routine =1 and =2 respectively).

```
elements={{"SiO2", "Al2O3", "FeO", "MgO", "CaO", "Na2O", "K2O", "TiO2","P2O5","MnO", "Cr2O3"}}
```

[image: PCA]

I used this very naive routine (see below), which despite of this fits for this simple case with a fixed number of 11 elements.

```
dataPlot2 = ListPlot[FkFl2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AxesLabel -> {"F" <> ToString[k], "F" <> ToString[l]}];
blabelEl1 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 1]], {FkFl2[[1, 1]], FkFl2[[1, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl1 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[1, 1]], FkFl2[[1, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl2 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 2]], {FkFl2[[2, 1]], FkFl2[[2, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl2 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[2, 1]], FkFl2[[2, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl3 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 3]], {FkFl2[[3, 1]], FkFl2[[3, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl3 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[3, 1]], FkFl2[[3, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl4 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 4]], {FkFl2[[4, 1]], FkFl2[[4, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl4 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[4, 1]], FkFl2[[4, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl5 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 5]], {FkFl2[[5, 1]], FkFl2[[5, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl5 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[5, 1]], FkFl2[[5, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl6 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 6]], {FkFl2[[6, 1]], FkFl2[[6, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl6 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[6, 1]], FkFl2[[6, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl7 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 7]], {FkFl2[[7, 1]], FkFl2[[7, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl7 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[7, 1]], FkFl2[[7, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl8 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 8]], {FkFl2[[8, 1]], FkFl2[[8, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl8 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[8, 1]], FkFl2[[8, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl9 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 9]], {FkFl2[[9, 1]], FkFl2[[9, 2]]}],PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl9 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[9, 1]], FkFl2[[9, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl10 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 10]], {FkFl2[[10, 1]], FkFl2[[10, 2]]}], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl10 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[10, 1]], FkFl2[[10, 2]]}}]];
blabelEl11 = Graphics[Text[elements[[1, 11]], {FkFl2[[11, 1]], FkFl2[[11, 2]]}], PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];
blineEl11 = Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[11, 1]], FkFl2[[11, 2]]}}]];
Show[dataPlot2, blabelEl1, blabelEl2, blabelEl3, blabelEl4, blabelEl5, blabelEl6, blabelEl7, blabelEl8, blabelEl9, blabelEl10, blabelEl11, blineEl1, blineEl2, blineEl3, blineEl4, blineEl5, blineEl6, blineEl7, blineEl8, blineEl9, blineEl10, blineEl11]
```

It would be so nice if a could treat a variable number of elements. Do you have any suggestion? I tried with loops (For, Do + Show) but I was not successful in plotting all (data points, lines, labels) at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an interactive approach using `Tooltip` and `DynamicWrapper`. The data is reformatted.

```
f = DynamicModule[{col = Black}, 
   DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[Style[#, col, Bold]], 
    If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red; 
     pos = {Red, Thickness[0.01], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {#2, #3}}]}, 
     col = Black; pos = {}]]] &
dat = {#1, Sequence @@ ##2} & @@@ Thread[{elements[[1]], FkFl2}];
col = ColorData[3, #] & /@ Range[11];
With[{g = 
   MapThread[{#1, 
      Tooltip[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {#2[[2]], #2[[3]]}}]}, #2[[1]], 
       TooltipStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold, 16]]} &, {col, dat}]},
 Row[{
   Dynamic@
    Graphics[Append[g, pos], ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> True, 
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"F1", "F2"}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], Column[f @@@ dat]}]]
```

[image]

Or with a legend. Using `LineLegend` causes flashing thick red arrow, so custom legend:

```
With[{g = 
   MapThread[{#1, 
      Tooltip[{Arrow[{{0, 0}, {#2[[2]], #2[[3]]}}]}, #2[[1]], 
       TooltipStyle -> Directive[Red, Bold, 16]]} &, {col, dat}]}, 
 Row[{Dynamic@
    Graphics[Append[g, pos], ImageSize -> 400, Axes -> True, 
     Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"F1", "F2"}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], 
   Grid@Transpose[{Graphics[{#, Line[{{0, 0}, {2, 0}}]}, 
         PlotRange -> {-0.1, 0.1}, ImageSize -> {30, 2}] & /@ col, 
      f @@@ dat}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
FkFl2 = {{0.108705, 0.505448}, {0.358493, 0.0753008}, {-0.418082, 
    0.0156307}, {-0.00893736, -0.519801}, {0.341173, -0.170573}, \
{0.139561, 0.546447}, {0.0991457, 0.236118}, {-0.408699, 
    0.060441}, {-0.371379, 0.0200262}, {-0.411535, 
    0.0433609}, {0.254496, -0.28112}};

elements = {"SiO2", "Al2O3", "FeO", "MgO", "CaO", "Na2O", "K2O", 
   "TiO2", "P2O5", "MnO", "Cr2O3"};

Grid[({#, ChemicalData[#, "Name"]} & /@ elements) /. 
   ChemicalData[__] :> "", Frame -> All] // Quiet
```

[image]

```
Graphics[
 {Line[{{0, 0}, #}] & /@ FkFl2,
  Text[#[[1]], #[[2]], -Sign[#[[2]]]] & /@ 
   Transpose[{elements, FkFl2}]},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> ((MinMax[#] + {-.1, .1}) & /@ {FkFl2[[All, 1]], 
     FkFl2[[All, 2]]})]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you are using 10.4 or later version.

```
ListPlot[MapThread[Labeled,{FkFl2,Flatten[elements]}],AxesLabel->
{"F1","F2"},PlotRange->CoordinateBounds[FkFl2,Scaled[1/7]],ImageSize->Large,
Epilog->{Line[{{0,0},#}&/@FkFl2]},PlotStyle->Black]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Show[ListPlot[FkFl2, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
AxesLabel -> {"F" <> ToString[k], 
  "F" <> ToString[l]}], #] &@({Graphics[
  Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[#, 1]], FkFl2[[#, 2]]}}]], 
 Graphics[Text[elements[[1, #]], {FkFl2[[#, 1]], FkFl2[[#, 2]]}]]} & /@ Range[1, Length[FkFl2]])
```

You will need to read about `Map`. Also [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica) is extremely useful.

Answer (score 1):

Using what you already have done just make these functions and then use `Table` inside `Show`

```
 blabelEl[i_] := 
 Graphics[Text[elements[[1, i]], {FkFl2[[i, 1]], FkFl2[[i, 2]]}], 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}];

blineEl[i_] := 
Graphics[Line[{{0, 0}, {FkFl2[[i, 1]], FkFl2[[i, 2]]}}]];

Show[dataPlot2, Table[{blabelEl[i], blineEl[i]}, {i, 1, Length[FkFl2]}]]
```

Comment: I believe `Flatten` is not necessary .

Comment: Yes you r right. I should have checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Epilog to add labels to a plot,

```
ListPlot[
 FkFl2,
 Epilog -> {
   {Text[#1, 1.2*#2], 
      Line[{{0, 0}, #2}]} & @@@ (Transpose@{First@elements, FkFl2})
   }
 , PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}
 ]
```