# Adding labels to close points in a ListPlot

Tags: plotting, labeling

I need to add labels to points in a `ListPlot`. The only problem is that the points can be closely located so if I do it in my usual way it becomes messy.

I would like no label overlaps another not any point in the plot (something like in the figure below or better).

There is some solution that comes close to solving my problem: [How to position text labels automatically to not overlap other graphics elements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33006/how-to-position-text-labels-automatically-to-not-overlap-other-graphics-elements) , but still in proposed solution if several points are close the labels start to overlap! It happens because they draw the label always close to the point.

[image]

Here is the code to generate a cluster of close points I need to label:

```
data = Table[{t, Re[3 Exp[I 5/2 t]] - t, Im[5 Exp[I 5/2 t]]}, {t, 0, 10}];
dataPlot = ListPlot[data[[All, {2, 3}]], PlotStyle -> PointSize -> Large];
labels = Text[Label  #[[1]], 1.1 #[[{2, 3}]]] & /@ data;
Show[dataPlot, Graphics[{Red, labels}], 
PlotRange -> 50 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

which gives the following result:

[image]

Comment: How about labeling them in another plane (in 3D)?

Comment: Have you seen [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)?

Comment: @Edmund Tooltip is not very useful for print version I need finaly

Comment: @SimonWoods No! in proposed solution if points are close the labels starts to overlaps! It happens because they draw the label always close to the point.

Comment: Could you post code to generate a suitable example plot? It would make it  easier for people to test their ideas.

Comment: @SimonWoods Done

Comment: perhaps you can modify [this answer by ubpdqn](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114938/125) to a related question.

Answer (score 6):

You could plot each data point with a marker that is also its label. Like so

```
labels = CharacterRange["A", "Z"];
SeedRandom[42]; 
data = List /@ Transpose[Table[RandomSample[Range[26]], 2]]

ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> labels]
```

[image: plot]

#### Note

Each data point must be wrapped in a list. That is,

```
{{{14, 3}}, {{21, 25}}, ..., {{26, 12}}, {{12, 4}}}
```

not the usual

```
{{14, 3}, {21, 25}, ..., {26, 12}, {12, 4}}
```

#### Update

If you need supply long annotations, consider making the annotations in legends associated with the point markers. For example,

```
longForm = # <> " annotation" & /@ labels;
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Black, PlotMarkers -> labels, PlotLegends -> longForm]
```

[image: plot_with_legend]

Comment: Well.. It is good idea, but I need to add real labels, which are sometimes longer than one symbol

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков. I didn't use symbols; I used strings. They can be any length and contain spaces and punctuation in them.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков. I have added another plot showing how I would handle long labels without cluttering up the main plot

Answer (score 6):

```
colors = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[;; Length@data]];

Deploy@DynamicModule[{pt = ({##2} & @@@ data), pt2 =(4 {##2} & @@@ data), 
   lbls = Module[{i = 1}, Framed["Label" <> ToString[#], 
                 FrameStyle -> colors[[i++]]] & @@@ data]}, 
  ListPlot[List /@ pt, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
   PlotRange -> 50 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
   Epilog -> (Dynamic[{colors[[#]], Line[{pt2[[#]], pt[[#]]}], 
                   Locator[Dynamic@pt2[[#]], Style[lbls[[#]], colors[[#]], "Panel"]]} & /@ 
                 Range[Length@pt]])]]
```

After manual adjustment of labels using the locators:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ... couldn't figure out how to set the initial positions of labels to minimize the manual adjustments.

Comment: Very nice! Almost. It is even better when it is possible to move labels to get nice final figure. Still it will take a lot of time since I have about 100 points. Maybe it is possible to add some "physical interactions" between labels so they "drop down"?